# Safari and Chrome modifying form data on back button

Tags: c#, safari, google-chrome, back-button

I getting this weird issue in Safari & Chrome (works in Firefox and IE).

1. I start off with this checkbox list which has the first item 'A' checked, and item 'B' and 'C' unchecked
2. I then navigate to another page which orders the items that appear in the checkbox list
3. I change the order of the items in the list so it now goes 'B', 'A', 'C'
4. I press the back button
5. The page is re-fetched from the server (I have caching disabled), I check the response sent from the server, and the item 'A' is still checked and no longer the first item in the list.
6. !!!Weird Behaviour!!! The page has loaded in the browser with the new order 'B', 'A', 'C', but 'A' isn't checked, instead the first item 'B' is checked.

Somehow it appears that the position of the check item has been restored by pressing the back button, and the form data has been discarded that was sent from the server.

When I refresh the page the order is 'B', 'A', 'C' and item 'A' is now checked, and everything looks ok.

On both occasions the Page has IsPostBack set to false.

Is this a bug in web kit?

Tried, clearing the cache, going into private browsing mode, clearing the history. Still same behavior.

Comment: That shouldn't be tagged as C# I guess.

Answer (score 5):

We had a similar issue with form data being "restored" by Webkit, even though the page state changed in the mean time.

Similar post [Safari and Chrome back button changes hidden and submit values in forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373872/safari-and-chrome-back-button-changes-hidden-and-submit-values-in-forms) gave a good hint that worked for us. By adding `autocomplete="off"` to all forms on the page we could solve this.

Comment: Oh my God, you saved my life! I've been banging my head for two days till I found this autocomplete solution! I had some search form on page which was returning cheeky form data on back button click in Safari and Google Chrome. Surprisingly the IE worked perfectly well on back button click. So thanks again for this.

Answer (score 0):

See this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/eGutT/9/

This is happening to me as well.  This seems like a pretty fundamental flaw as the use-case is so simple, and most likely common.  I've already run into this issue in two places in different projects.  If disabling the session actually avoids this issue, it's not a *real* fix, as most clients won't even know about this option, or care.