# Form search submission help

Tags: html, forms

Hey guys, I have a form and there are 4 buttons possible for the user to click to submit. One searches for everything, another for users, another for clips, and the fourth for topics. Now my question is that the buttons has name=category and value=(type of search) and what I intend to do is send the user to the search result page with the category=value in the address bar(using GET method). This is working fine on firefox but it isn't working at all using google chrome. Any help? Here's the code:

```
<form method="get" action="search.php" name="search" onsubmit="return Validate();">
        <input type="text" class="searchit" title="Search..." name="search" id="search" /><br/>

        <label><span> </span> <input name="submitter" type="submit" value="Search" class="searchsubmitButton" id="submitter" /></label>
        <span class="searchfor">Search for:</span>
        <label><span> </span> <input name="c" type="submit" value="Users" class="searchsubmitButton" id="submitter" /></label>
        <label><span> </span> <input name="c" type="submit" value="Clips" class="searchsubmitButton" id="submitter" /></label>
        <label><span> </span> <input name="c" type="submit" value="Topics" class="searchsubmitButton" id="submitter" /></label>
    </form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't dowrk in google chrome"? Are you getting error messages? Undesired output? Give us a little more information and we'll be able to help you better. :D

Comment: It isn't working since in the address bar I'm not getting c=users or c=clips or c=topics, just search=(search query).

Comment: As I suggested below, take the <input> field outside the <label></label> tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because your input fields are inside the `<label></label>` tags ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this thread: [Safari and Chrome back button changes hidden and submit values in forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373872/safari-and-chrome-back-button-changes-hidden-and-submit-values-in-forms)

The easiest solution I can think of is for you to create a hidden field called "c". Then, when the submit button is clicked, set the value (Users, Clips or Topics) in "c" hidden field first before submitting the form.

Comment: :D... Okay, I'm on crack today... I fixed the link. :)