# Have chrome remember html/data?

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, input

With firefox if I modify the DOM and leave the page i can hit back and everything will return to as it was which is nice. When I try that with chrome it completely forgets the dom. I specifically am looking at remembering the files a user picked when using

```
<input type="file" name="somename" multiple>
```

How do I have chrome remember it so hitting back/forward doesn't reset the form?

Comment: Are you using multiple forms on page? Are you using autocomplete on some fields/forms? Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373872/safari-and-chrome-back-button-changes-hidden-and-submit-values-in-forms (see accepted answer).

Comment: @Kamil: One form  and no autocomplete attr on it

Comment: Im not sure how this will work for `type=file` and `multiple`: maybe try to turn on `autocomplete` attr. If this will not help - you probably have to use some fancy tricks with JS and cookies to store form somehow.

Comment: @Kamil: nevermind. A hard refresh made all the code work correctly