# Restoring form state with back button and "sortable" forms issue (Chrome and safari but not Firefox)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-chrome

I'm writing this to document a current (apparent) bug.

Situation: 
Given a webapp where users can view and sort tabular data (it is loaded from DOM, and sortable via javascript). They can use checkboxes and a buttons to take action on what is viewed.

If you use the back button to go back to the tabular data page, then the browser fills in the states of the checkboxes. This is expected behaviour.

Complication: 
If you sort the table first (an in-DOM sort using javascript) and then fill in the checkboxes and go to another page, and then use the back button to go back then browsers behave differently.

Currently Chrome (58) and Safari (10.1) reloads the form and tabular data in the original (not the js-sorted) order, but restore the inputs in the order they were clicked (ie ignoring any ids for the inputs -- just their order in the DOM at the time) -- this results in very surprising behaviour (the form at first glance seems to be what you expect, but different form elements have been restored with different data)

However Firefox (v50.0) reload the form and tabular data in the js-sorted order, and the restored inputs are correct.

I've documented this more fully at https://timdiggins.github.io/back-button-restore-sorted-inputs/

Ideally the browsers would store their input data against the input's id rather than its order in the DOM, or would cached the DOM order too.

I'll answer this myself with a workaround, but I'm hoping someone will come up with a better suggestion.

Or alternatively point out anywhere in HTML5 specs that say that form's DOM shouldn't be sortable?  (ie. is it possible that Chrome and Webkit are behaving to spec here).

Comment: Thank you for documenting this issue. Still there in Chrome 66..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found three ways of working around this. Two which are very reliable, but each lose functionality, and one which I am in two minds about

1) Disable dynamic sorting in the initial form (obviously).

2) Disable saving form state for all of the form elements with autocomplete="off" (on every input, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2458153/109175). Optionally could skip this for browsers (like Firefox) that have unproblematic behaviour (in my use case Firefox never used).

3) An option that occurred to me is to make sure that the order is reset to the original DOM order when form state is saved. This might mean adding a before submit handler on the form (easy enough) but in order to ensure the form is restored correctly when navigating away with a simple link `<a>`, this might mean adding a callback before executing links -- this wouldn't cover javascript based navigation.

4) Another option which occurs to me, is to focus on the reordering process -- either to convert it from js to a page reload or to use pushState or replaceState from the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

Both 3 and 4 seem clever, but (for my use cases) I'm inclined to go with one of 1 or 2 and deal with the reduced functionality.

Comment: Better outcome but more work -- load the "next page" not as a new document but as an overlay, and use History pushstate to go back to the sorted state.